# MediaElement not allowing 100% width

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm trying to get the MediaElementPlayer's width to be 100% of the screen which is fine and all until it doesn't stop adding width:320px to the container even though I remove every instance of it in the JS file. Anyways a live version of what I'm working on is at tonarnia.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Typo, I set DefaultVideoWidth instead of DefaultAudioWidth.